# Using scope in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have this scope in my model:

```
public function scopeValid($query){
  return $query->where('value_from', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('value_to', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to show two text in my blade `valid` or `expired` depend on their `value_from` & `value_to` columns, but all i get is same result for both types.

I get `valid` for both valid and expired coupons that i have.

here is how i try to do it:

```
foreach($coupons as $coupon){
  if($coupon->Valid()){
    $validation = 'Valid';
  }else{
    $validation = 'Expired';
  }
}
```

what should i go?

## UPDATE

`my blade view`

[image: screen1]

`my database`
[image: screen2]

`my full function`

```
public function index()
    {
      $coupons = Coupon::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
      $categories = Category::all();

      foreach($coupons as $coupon){
        if($coupon->valid()){
          $validation = 'Valid';
        }else{
          $validation = 'Expired';
        }
      }
      return view('admin.coupons.index', compact('coupons', 'categories', 'validation'));
    }
```

`my full model`

```
public function scopeValid($query){
        return $query->where('value_from', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('value_to', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you share full code like: Model::valid()->get();

Comment: @RashedulIslamSagor that's the full code, which part you need more?

Comment: try dumping $query
                ->where('value_from', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('value_to', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->get()->toArray();

Comment: @Riccardo in my model?

Comment: in the function, just to check if we are comparing correct data types

Comment: @Riccardo i get my coupon info

Comment: I'm still not sure what raw data are but are you maybe comparing "2018-05-01" with a different date type?

Comment: @Riccardo already solved, thanks bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, no need to use `scope` but in your can use `accessor` as the data already being fetched:

In your model:

```
public function getIsValidAttribute()
{
  $now = Carbon::now();

  return Carbon::parse($this->value_from)->lt($now) && Carbon::parse($this->value_to)->gt($now);

}
```

And finally called it in `blade view`:

```
@foreach ($coupons as $coupon
  @if($coupon->isValid)
    <span>Valid</span>
  @else
    <span>Expired</span>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: still says valid for both types

Comment: see updated answer. Does `$this->value_from` return carbon instance already if you `dd` it out?

Comment: Again, see updated answer, just choose either one return statement

Comment: for `return Carbon::parse($this->value_from)` both are valid, and for `return $this->value_from->lt($now) && $this->value_to->gt($now);` gives error `Call to a member function lt() on string`

Comment: I guess it not returning Carbon instance

Comment: You call `if($coupon->isValid){` inside a controller or view? actually you need to call it directly to the view when rendering content. If you call inside a controller, then nothing happens as it will not change or add default collection

Comment: and it's working in blade, no way to use it in controller?

Comment: can work in controller, but you must update the existing collection instance

Comment: i think is fine this way :), appreciate you helps

Comment: Much Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get a boolean out of a query instance, an accesor is better for this situation, the main problem here is that you are using a custom date format `d-m-Y` and the `toDateTimeString` method is generating a whole `datetime`, try using the `format` to make the comparison equivalent:

```
public function getValidAttribute($value){
  $date =  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
  return $this->value_from >= $date && $this->value_to <= $date;
}
```

And to call the scope you don't use capital letter:

```
foreach($coupons as $coupon){
  if($coupon->valid){
    $validation = 'Valid';
  }else{
    $validation = 'Expired';
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @mafortis I think you had the comparation backwards

Comment: @mafortis As other answer suggested, for that use case you actually shouldn't be using a scope, an accesor is more useful, check it out now

Comment: @mafortis The problem is that you are using a custom format, test my update

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are not even calling the same function, maybe you need to change

```
$coupon->Valid()
```

to

```
scopeValid($coupon)
```

to begin with.

Assuming that $coupon is a Collection I think you should change the function to something like:

```
public function scopeValid($query){
        $valid_result_count = $query
                ->where('value_from', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('value_to', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                ->count();
        return ($valid_result_count > 0);
    }
```

Comment: add to the question the values of this fields for the $coupon you are testing with